# Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS on mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS about every 5th run of my iPad application in the following line of code. I have run Zombies, but the app just crashes and Instruments doesn't show any zombies, it just stops recording.

```
[self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
```

Below is the code I am using in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(contextChanged:) 
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
                                           object:nil];

  .....blah blah balh........

  return YES;
}



- (void) contextChanged:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    if(self.managedObjectContext)
    {
      if ([notification object] == [self managedObjectContext] ) return;

      if(![NSThread isMainThread])
      {
          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextChanged:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
      }

      [self.managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
      [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

I am not sure how else to debug this? What is weird is that it only crash every 5th - 7th time I run the app (I am always resetting content on simulator each time I run for testing).

Comment: I'm a little confused by the code...partway through `contextChanged:` you check the thread and then execute that same code again on the main thread?  Seems like you'd want that check to guard the *entire* code of that method so that it only executes once.  Also, inconsistent crashes in threaded code are a sign that you've done something that isn't thread-safe.

Comment: The first check is to be sure AppDelegate has a managedObjectContext. The 2nd if makes sure the didSsaveNotification didn't come from AppDelegates NSManagedObjectContext (as we don't need to merge if the change happened to itself).  The 3rd "if" is to say if NOT MainThread then perform the method again but on mainThread.  I did just change the last two lines by throwing them in and ELSE for readability and make sure they are not run if after MainThread check. Will update if that helps.